# use `SplitArrayField` instead of `SimpleArrayField` in ModelForm

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-forms

I have model with `ArrayField` and I want use `ModelForm`. Django by default use `SimpleArrayField` but I need `SplitArrayField`. I get my data from json and I use form only for validation and I don't need input widgets. (I use client side rendering)

```
class Profile(models.Model):
  phone = ArrayField(CharField(max_length=20, validators=[some_validator]))

class ProfileForm(ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = Profile

form = ProfileForm(data={"phone":["555-5555","444-4444"]})
form.validate()
```

How I can use `SplitArrayField` in `ModelForm`?

Comment: how is it about postgres?..

Comment: `from django.contrib.postgres.forms import SimpleArrayField` array field is postgres specific field

Comment: probably this tag is not related though. http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql/info

Comment: @seyed, did my answer help you? Please accept and upvote.

Answer (score 2):

I solve my problem with `field_classes` in `Meta` class:

```
class ProfileForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        field_classes = {
            'phone': SplitArrayField, # or any custom field
        }
```

**note**:

`SplitArrayField` is not good enough for me so I create my own [array form field](https://gist.github.com/smmoosavi/349052c371975ae5efe7d3b678f60aa1)

Answer (score 0):

I think with pure django this is not possible at the moment. There is [ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/26654#no1) which proposes the the possibility to use a `SplitArrayField`.

But you could use this package: [django_postgres_extensions](https://github.com/primal100/django_postgres_extensions).
There you can use a `SplitArrayField` by defining the `form_size` parameter:

```
from django_postgres_extensions.models.fields import ArrayField

class Product(models.Model):
    keywords = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=20), default=[],  form_size=10, blank=True)
```